# A question about squares

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

The numbers from 1 to $ 2013^2 $ are written row by row into a table consisting of $ 2013 \times 2013 $ cells. Afterwards, all columns and all rows containing at least one of the perfect squares $ 1, 4, 9, \cdots, 2013^2 $ are simultaneously deleted.
How many cells remain?
I checked this operation replacing $2013$ by smaller numbers, and if my arithmetic is not wrong it came out to be the number of quadratic non-residues $\mod n$. Is it true? Anyways what would be the number of remaining cells?

Comment: "came out to be the number of quadratic non-residues $mod$ $n$"

did you miss some term ?

Comment: A proposition that is true for any n x n is that if you delete only the columns containing a square, the number of remaining columns will equal the number of quadratic non-residues.  If you also delete rows containing a square and count the remaining cells, the number will equal the number of quadratic non-residues only if all rows except one are deleted.  This happens to be so for some cases with small numbers, eg 4x4 and 5x5, but is not true in general.

Comment: The quadratic residues part is my observation, it may not be true at all. But I want to know how many cells will remain after doing this operation.

Comment: And please can someone give an example of $n$ where the number of cells remaining is not the number of quadratic non-residues $\mod n$?

Comment: A simple example is n = 3 (zero cells remaining since 1 is in row 1, 4 in row 2 and 9 in row 3, one quadratic non-residue (2)).  n = 2013 is also an example, since there will be many rows not deleted in the lower regions of the square, the intervals between the larger squares being greater than the length of a row.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation to comment yet, so I have to post it as an answer, although it is not really an answer.

Did you check for n=3 ? Unless I have mistaken you in some way I get 0 remaining cells:

***1*** 2 3

***4*** 5 6

7 8 ***9***

All rows are removed and no cells are remaining. But 3 has the quadratic non-redesidue 2.

I also checked n=11 and got 10 remaining cells. But we only have 5 non-residues mod 11.

While writing this text I noticed something that is certainly true:
The number of remaining columns is in fact the number of non-residues. This is easy to prove, since every column has integers in it that are congruent modulo n.

So the number of remaining cells is certainly a multiple of the number of non-residues.

Edit: With a computer search I got 503 remaining rows and 1641 remaining columns which gives a whooping 825423 remaining cells.

Edit2: I think I answered what you asked:

1. For arbitary n, are the number of remaining cells the number of quad. non-res.? No, but a multiple thereof. (Short proof: Every column represents a equivalentclass mod n and is removed iif there is a square in it.)
2. How many cells are left if n=2013? Computer search says 825423. You get the columns by calculating the quad. non-residues. You get the rows by finding all rows that don't contain a square (Loop through i=1..2013 and "delete" the row which has the number $\frac{i^2-1}{2013}$ (Integer division)). I don't see how it would be possible to calculate the rows in another way but bruteforce. Althoug you can make some small improvements on the algorithm, I can't think of a way to find a closed form.

Edit3:Ok, I somehow skipped your last sentence. But barto said, the number of remaining columns are the non residues and the number of rows is the formula Ivan Loh provided. So your question is answered.

Comment: Oh I see I need to work on my arithmetic. But the actual problem is still unsolved. I only wanted to tell you what I found, and sadly I was wrong. But can we try and do the problem actually given? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It may be significant that the number of remaining rows in 2013 x 2013 equals (2013 - 1)/4 = 503.  That may give a clue to a closed form formula for the number of remaining rows in n x n.

Comment: For $x \leq 1006$, we have $(x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1 \leq 2013$. Thus it is not possible to skip a row until we get to $1007^2, 1008^2, \ldots$. We have $\lceil \frac{1006^2}{2013} \rceil =503$. Thus the first $503$ rows have a square. Now for the remaining $2013-503=1510$ rows, there are $2013-1006=1007$ remaining squares from $1007^2$ onwards, of which no two can be in the same row. This gives another $1007$ rows with squares, so there are $503$ rows with no squares.

Comment: @Michael You gave a value. Suppose I replaced $2013$ by $n$ then what would it be? And Ivan I ask for number of cells, not number of rows, thanks though to both of you.

Comment: @Joybangla Ivan's method proves that for odd $n$ we always have $\frac{n-1}2-\lceil\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}\rceil$ square-free rows. Multiply this by the number of quadratic non-residues to get the number of cells. The even case is similar, the number of square-free rows becomes $\frac n2-\lceil\frac n4\rceil$. Note that for odd $n$, $\lceil\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}\rceil=\lceil\frac{n-2}4\rceil$.